# How to make debug code using #ifdef directive. Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, debugging, conditional-compilation

i want to make a question about developing using #ifdef directive.

I want do make some code in objective-c only for debug use, for example:

in main function do this:

```
#define DEBUG_LEVEL
```

in my interface do this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_LEVEL
BOOL editorIsDragged;
BOOL editorIsSelected;
#endif
```

.... other property

```
#ifdef #DEBUG_LEVEL
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL editorIsDragged;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL editorIsSelected;
#endif
```

then in my implementation do this:

```
#ifdef #DEBUG_LEVEL
@synthetize editorIsDragged, editorIsSelected;
#endif
```

but i receve an error because in synthetize `editorIsDragged` and `editorIsSelected` are not defined.
If i try to define my own setter/getter method I receive the same error, because my vars (`editorIsDragged` and `editorIsSelected`) does not exist for XCode!

I in C use this method for write only debug code, but in obj-c what i must use??

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you put your #define DEBUG_LEVEL in a header file that gets included in all places that needs to know it? Like setting in in the build settings or putting in the *.pch. And I'm not sure if that a typo but you have also #define #DEBUG_LEVEL (see the second hash?) in the code here.

Comment: Also, NDBEUG (No Debug) is the standard macro used for this sort of thing, although it can get a bit ugly with double negative conditionals.